# ExtJS Not Loading Ext-all.js

Tags: extjs

Why?! A very simple little ExtJS demo I'm trying to get working in my S3 bucket, and when the page loads I'm getting the 403 Forbiden error for ext-all.js.

What gives? You can test this here:

https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mazzoochi-extjs-bucket/index.html

Thanks,

(index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Mazzochi First ExtJS App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

   <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/classic/theme-crisp/resources/theme-crisp-all.css" / >
   <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.0.0/ext-all.js"> </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var myComp1 = Ext.create("Ext.container.Component",{

            html: 'component1'
        });

        var myComp2 = Ext.create("Ext.container.Component",{

            html: 'component2'
        });

        var myComp3 = Ext.create("Ext.container.Component",{

            html: 'component3'
        });

        var mycontainer = Ext.create("Ext.container.Container",{

            items:[myComp1,myComp2,myComp3],
            layout: 'vbox'
        });

        Ext.application({
            name: 'MyApp',
            launch: function () {
                Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                    items: [

                            mycontainer 

                    ]
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
    <body>

        <div id="MyDivId"> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because web browser can not load resources.

[image]

Use command

```
sencha app build
```

for production

See: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/guides/quick_start/going_to_production.html#quick_start-_-going_to_production_-_build_your_application

Comment: Thanks for responding Do Nhu Vy.  I will work on that now.

Comment: Do Nhu Vy could you see this issue-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50866733/confused-about-deploying-a-sencha-touch-app I am not clear about where to deploy a Sencha Touch app.