# Sencha Touch Deployment Options?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I am very new to ExtJS and Sencha Touch.  I am trying to learn Sencha Touch, and was able to get a demo version running locally using 'sencha watch'.  But I want to deploy this somewhere like Heroku, Azure, AWS or wherever.

How do I get this in production?

I'd appreciate it, 
CMazz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get this in production?

Developing your application simply means editing source code and refreshing the browser. All source files are dynamically loaded on demand. There's no building process involved. When it comes to deployment, Sencha Cmd provides the following four build environment options:

- **Production environment**

  Creates a production build that is normally hosted on a web server and serves multiple clients (devices). The build is offline-capable using HTML 5 application cache, and is enabled to perform over-the-air updates. You can build using below command :-

  ```
   sencha app build //Or
   sencha app build production
  ```
- **Testing environment**

  Intended for QA prior to production. All JavaScript and CSS source files are bundled, but not minified, which makes it easier to debug. You can build using below command :-

  ```
  sencha app build testing
  ```

After run the following command, In you app there is `build` folder. See below screenshot

[image: img]

Now if want to host production then go inside of production folder then after build you code in to your web server (Heroku, Azure, AWS or wherever)  and same for testing environment.

For more details you can refers [`Sencha docs`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/index.html)

Comment: Narendra Jadhav thanks for replying. I am able to get my app working locally using 'sencha app watch'. Dtarts up on localhost:1841 just fine. So I run 'sencha app build production' and I see a production folder.  In that I see another folder Mazzo.sencha.touch.demo inside that are the archive, classic, modern, resources directories, and the cache.appcache, classic.json classic.jsonp, index.html, modern.json and modern.jsonp files.  Is it these directories and files that need to be in the root of web server directory?
When I ftp those directories and files into Azure app service it fails.

Comment: How would I put this in Heroku?

Comment: *need to be in the root of web server directory* yes because `index.html` should be on root folder. `index.html` automatically load all required file on server